# How do you capture a variable number of patterns on the same line using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

So, I have been asked to create a java file that reads characters, pulls information using regex, and prints it out for an assignment. I'm not too knowledgeable with regular expressions, but I can complete the assignment assuming that each line only contains either one example of the text I need or does not contain any. But the problem arises when I attempt to collect multiple pieces of text on the same line. Particularly if there is text within the line that I am not supposed to read.

For example;

[Here is an example line that I might have to read example@such.com and I have to extra the username addresses pleasehelpme@such.com see?]

If you could explain your answers in layman's terms, it would help significantly.

I have tried looking up answers but the closest I could find to one is https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html, a basic regular expressions page and a site that showed an example of scanning for two different patterns. Suffice to say, I'm fairly new to this and I could really use help.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\S*([a-zA-Z]+)@$");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(texttoread[i]);
        while(mat.find()) 
        {
           Holdingvar = Holdingvar + mat.group();
    }
//Keep in mind that this still needs to be loaded into an array so that I can 
//print them all out.
```

As I previously stated, it works perfectly if a line only contains one of what I want or does not contain what I want. In which case, it prints the name of the address.

Overwise, it only prints out the latest address and the address is listed after all the lines that contain only one address within them. Which is a problem because I would prefer for them to be printed out in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example regex you have uses a `$` pattern, which matches the end-of-input. As such, it can only ever match once. It's a bad example of what you're trying to do.

Instead, let us keep it simple: Define an email address as an `@` at-sign, with text before and after, and define text as "not whitespace".

The regex would then be: `\S+@\S+`
I.e. one or more "not whitespace", an `@` sign, then one or more "not whitespace".

This pattern can match multiple times in a string:

```
String input = "Here is an example line that I might have to read example@such.com and I have to extra the username addresses pleasehelpme@such.com see?";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+@\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

*Output*

```
example@such.com
pleasehelpme@such.com
```

Comment: I get what you are trying to do. But the main problem is that I have to put them into an array. It would be more efficient the way you suggested, but that's one of the constraints I was given.

Comment: @StackUndertow So you question was not about regex? Your question is how to add values to an array? Since you don't know how many you'll find, add to a `List`. If you absolutely need an array, then convert the `List` to an array after the loop.

Comment: No. I know how to add values to an array. The problem is, I need to extract multiple values on the same line with regex and fit them all into an array as separate entities. Also, the \\S+ at the end of your suggestion is somehow causing the program to read the text after the .com. Is there any way to call a blank space or an end of a line?

Comment: @StackUndertow So add the emails you find in the loop to an array. Since you claim to know how to add to an array, I don't see the problem. --- *"read the text after the .com"* Don't know what you mean. You can clearly see in the output in the answer that it stops at the space after the `.com`, so I don't understand why you're asking how to make it stop at a blank space, when it obviouly is already doing so.

Comment: Truthfully, some of the lines of code end with @ followed by a blank space and then a few characters. The proposed solution is reading those characters which is bad. The problem cropped up with I removed the $ though I suppose that was bound to happen if it really does signify the end of a line (I believe you when you say it does).

Comment: @StackUndertow The code (my code that is) cannot do that, since there has to be at least one non-space following the @ sign (the `+` means 1-or-more), so it simply won't match *"@ followed by a blank space and then a few characters"*.

Comment: Well for whatever unknown reason, that is what is happening. I'll check the other pieces of code and see if something is up down the line. In the meanwhile. Thanks. If I remember this post when I reach the threshold to be able to upvote people, everyone who helped me is getting one.

Answer (score 1):

Some options to consider depending on your circumstances:

- If there is some 'optional' text that you want to ignore but it is a fairly fixed format, you can make a group optional by putting a ? after the brackets (if not present, it will come out as null when you call group() on the matcher with the relevant group number; also consider making it non-capturing with (:?...)? if you don't specifically need to refer to it). This generally assumes you're matching to the whole line rather than using find() to pull out mutliple elements within the line.
- As Andreas mentions, you don't have to match in relation the start/end of the line. By default, quantifiers such as + and * are "greedy": they'll match to as many characters as possible provided they still allow other parts of the expression to match, meaning that you don't always even need to specify the "anchors" (what comes before/after the match), and you can iterate through matches using find()
- But if necessary, you can specify the context that must come before/after a match, e.g. specify \b to refer to a "word boundary" (but see the Pattern documentation for the specific meaning that that has). If you need this option, look at the options for "look-ahead" and "look-behind" specifications in your pattern: in other words, this gives you the option of saying "find this pattern, assuming that pattern occurring just before it was ...".

It's a good idea to try and make your pattern as specific as you can while still matching the substrings you need to match. As a quick Internet search will show you, what is a good pattern to match an e-mail is a complex issue. Here is a very simplistic example (in reality, probably too simplistic, but the point is that it's a bit more specific than the expression you are currently using):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\.]+@[a-zA-Z\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+");

Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Why `group(0)` instead of just `group()`?

Comment: Oh, no particular reason - I guess it's just what I'm used to typing - they're defined as being equivalent.